# SVG Resize on smaller screen using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to figure out how can i resize preserveAspectRatio using JavaScript , i have an art that takes 70% of my screen with **viewBox of "0 0 750 500"** i tried to change this values to be responsive on all screens but i failed the only way to fix it on desktop screen is using **preserveAspectRatio="none"** , but when i scale the screen it shrinks to be an ugly art , what i am trying to achieve is how to resize SVG's on smaller screens while SVG has preserveAspectRatio = "none" ?

like this svg :

```
<svg id="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 432.53 432.53" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" y1="216.27" x2="432.53" y2="216.27" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#20c5e0"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#1be28c"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="216.27" cy="216.27" r="213.27" fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="6" stroke="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please show us some code... or you can simply give width, height to svg code.

Comment: added a circle svg for an example .

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the SVG in a parent container and give it a width and height in relative units

`preserveAspectRatio = "none"` needs to be removed in order for the image to resize proportionally

By default in SVG preserveAspectRatio = "xMidyMid meet"

```css
.container {
width:30vw;
height:30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 432.53 432.53" >
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" y1="216.27" x2="432.53" y2="216.27" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#20c5e0"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#1be28c"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="216.27" cy="216.27" r="213.27" fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="6" stroke="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that should be done with Js. You need to put your SVG in a div, and control that div's dimentions in CSS.

```
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg>...
</div>
```

```
.svg-container {
  width: 70%;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: it scaled perfectlly but its height has a problem , is there anyway i can control svg using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Width and height attribute in svg code. Or You can use css also.

```html
<svg id="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 432.53 432.53" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="200px" height="200px">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" y1="216.27" x2="432.53" y2="216.27" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#20c5e0"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#1be28c"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="216.27" cy="216.27" r="213.27" fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="6" stroke="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```